# Javascript new function constructor doesn't return the wanted value

Tags: javascript

```js
function Add(a, b){
 this.a = a, this.b = b;
 return this.a + this.b;
}

var add5 = new Add(2, 3); // ? add5 = 5

console.log(add);
```

"typeof add5" is Object, and "add5 instanceof Add" is true.

My question is:

1. On this case, how can I return value 5 that's I want?
2. In the function Add, I explicitly return 5, why do I get return Add instance?
3. Does new Function() only return this instance?

Comment: Why are you using `new` if you don't seem to want to create an object?

Answer (score 2):

*1. On this case, how can I return value 5 that's I want?*

With a simple function and with direct call without the `new` operator.

```js
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

document.write(add(2, 3));
```

*2. In the function Add, I explicitly return 5, why do I get return Add instance?*

*3. Does new Function() only return this instance?*

You get the instance, because of the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

> 3.The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation process.)

According to [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2522-providing-a-return-value-in-a-javascript-constructor.htm), a new instance does not return a [primitive data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive). You can only overwrite the return value (`this`) with an object.

Comment: _(Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation process.)_ I have a doubt with this line. Then why didn't it return a value in OP's case?

Comment: This answered the 2nd, 3rd question, thanks a lot.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Because the returned value was not an object.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah I read the algorithm to clear that. But I still confused about that. I have returned null from a constructor, though an object was returned instead of null. typeof null is object. right?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: while `typeof null` returns the string "object", `null` really is a primitive value of type Null.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this much simpler ...

```
function Add(a, b){
            return a + b;
}

var add = Add(2, 3);    // ? add = 5
console.log(add);
```

---

Or maybe this if you want a method related Instance

```
function AddNumbers(a, b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    return this;

}
AddNumbers.prototype.add = function(){
      var sum  = this.a+this.b;
      console.log(sum);
      return sum;
}

var addObject = new AddNumbers(2, 3);   // ? add = 5
addObject.add();
```

Comment: It's a good solution for the first question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The new operator is used to create an object. In your case, `add5.a` and `add5.b` are populated with 2 and 3 respectively.

You should do the following.

```
function Add(a, b){
    this.a = a, this.b = b;
    this.result = function(){
        return this.a + this.b;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
var add5 = new Add(2, 3);   // ? add5 = 5

console.log(add5.result());
```

Comment: It's a clever trick for the 1st question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the 'new' keyword since that creates a new object out of that function. Just call the function the following way.

```js
function Add(a, b){
 this.a = a, this.b = b;
 return this.a + this.b;
}

var add = Add(2, 3); // ? add = 5

console.log(add);
```

Comment: This answered the first question, thanks.